# How do I programmatically check an Android radio button with ripple animation?

Tags: android, animation, radio-button

tl;dr: When the user clicks an unrelated text view, I want a radio button to be selected with a ripple animation. performClick doesn't do this. What should I be doing instead?

I have a radio button with both a label and a longer description.

[image]

The general structure of my layout is this:

```
<RadioGroup>

  <RadioButton
      id="@+id/officialBusinessRadio"
      text="Official business" />

  <TextView
      id="@+id/officialBusinessCaption"
      text="This operates under a ..." />

  <!-- ... -->

</RadioGroup>
```

I've added an OnClickListener to the text view so that tapping on the caption selects the radio button:

```
officialBusinessCaption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    officialBusinessRadio.performClick();
  }
});
```

When I tap on the radio button itself or on its own text ("Official Business"), the radio button animates to selected and a ripple ink effect occurs. When I top on the caption text (and performClick is called), the radio button still animates to selected, but no ripple occurs.

Is there a more correct way to get this effect? That is, is there a better way to forward a click on the caption text view to the radio button? If not, is there a straightforward way to trigger the ripple effect on the radio button programmatically?

I would prefer against setting all the text using a string resource for the following reasons:

- I intend on styling the label and the caption differently.
- I want the radio vertically center aligned with the first line of text.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

I've hit this problem by population `RadioButton`s in a `RecyclerView`. All of them are set to `isClickable = false` because I override their selection according to another rule, but the way to trigger the selection to `true` is doing:

**Kotlin:**

```
    radioButton.post {
        radioButton.isChecked = true
    }
```

**Java:**

```
    radioButton.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            radioButton.setChecked(true);
        }
    })
```

before, I was doing `setChecked(true)` only and it wouldn't work.